# print out django request.META in a template

Tags: django, django-templates

I am trying to print out the values inside the request.META in a template but I cannot get it right. All I got is an error `Could not parse the remainder: '[i]' from 'REQ_META[i]'`

below is my code:
in my views.py

```
def index (request):
    template = loader.get_template('app/index.html')
    page_data = { 'REQ_META': request.META}
    context = RequestContext(request, page_data)
    return HttpResponse(template.render(context))
```

in index.html

```
{% for i in REQ_META %}
    {{ i }} = {{ REQ_META[i] }} <br />
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the right way to inspect the `request.META` objects would be using [`pdb`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/pdb.html) in the view, or using tools like [`django-debugtoolbar`](https://github.com/django-debug-toolbar/django-debug-toolbar).

In my opinion, django debug toolbar is an extremely handy tools for debugging purposes.

Regardless, Your issue is, `REQ_META` is a dictionary, and the way to parse the elements of the dictionary is:

```
{% for k, v in REQ_META %}
    {{ k }} = {{ v }} <br />
{% endfor %}
```

[Documentation here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#for)

Answer (score 0):

There is already an answer, but thought it could be useful for future use:

You just need to access the object like this `{{ REQ_META.i }}` instead of `{{ REQ_META[i] }}`

---

Another option is to use [django pprint template filter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#pprint)

```
{{ REQ_META|pprint }}
```

Which will always print nicely dict objects (and any other python object)